# How to custom wp query with pagination to look like an mansory grid?

Tags: php, wordpress, layout

Here's my code for simple wp-query with pagination. But I'm trying to edit the code to group each posts in their own groups in order to look like an mansory grid.

Here's my code:

```
        <?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>

<div class="proyectpost">
            //content here...

</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="postsectionbottom">
<div class="paginationbar">
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'show_all'           => True,
    'prev_next'          => False
) );
?>
</div>
<div class="backtotopbutton">
<a href="#" class="topbutton"></a>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and here's a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Usually, I would make several wp-queries in each div inside div like this example:

```
<div class="projectospostssection">
<div class="postleftcolumn">
<div class="postleftwidth">
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>              
            //content here...

</article><!-- #post-## -->  

            <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="postrightcolumn">
<div class="postrightwidth">
<div class="flexgrow">
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9&posts_per_page=2&offset=1' ); ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            //content here...
</article><!-- #post-## --> 

            <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that I'm trying to figure out how to group those posts into either divs or queries within this **page** query. It's kinda my first time to do a wp_query within a wp-query.... Any suggestion would be helpful.

What I'm hoping to do is to group the 4 rows into 2 groups. Inside the first group, I'm going to group the first three pictures in left column and the last picture in the right column and so on...like what I illustrated in the next picture with the red boxes as outer divs and the neon green boxes as inner divs.
[image]

Comment: Not really enough info, sorry.  Need a better image of what you're trying to accomplish.  What are the distinguishing characteristics of each "box"? Why is one vertical and one horizontal? What should the output be doing that makes it look like that? (FYI, I'm familiar with both wp_query and masonry, so I get the overall concept, but details matter)

Comment: Is this better? I added another picture with outlines highlighted with which I hoped to group the posts into...

Comment: Hi Kristina - that helps a LOT.  Now, the question is - the two groups do not appear to be the same.  Is there a pattern we can use? Or is it a "fixed" layout? Or something I'm not seeing / understanding?

Comment: This is the website(http://econ.com.sv/) that this code is for. On front page, you can see the posts I usually do under "PRYECTOS DESTACADOS", but the actual code that I wanted edited is in Proyectos page (http://econ.com.sv/?page_id=10). They are in flexbox grid which I will be editing with percentage and fixed heights like what I did for the home page.

Comment: So in the first green group, I will make the first two pictures both 50% and the bottom picture 100% within the 66% wide column and the second green group 33% wide.

Comment: Just curious - you do realize that masonry is done via javascript - because it has to calculate heights, sizes, etc. to figure out a nice "fit"?  IF you could assure the right proportions for each image, this could be done with CSS only, and some classes on each page, but that becomes a BIG answer....

Comment: Yes, I know about masonary but what I've seen so far depends on floats and I don't see how I can add it to wp query. So I thought that I can have better control over the layout if I can put the queries in the divs, but the problem is that the code in question is paged query so I was asking how i can put query inside paged query...

Comment: You don't wnat to put a query inside a query.  That's bad.  What you want to do is control the layout properly.  And masonry absolutely does **not** use floats, it uses `position:absolute` and javascript-calculated values for top / left to achieve the desired layout.

Comment: Okay, then I'll look into masonry again and see how I can make it work. It's also my first time using masonry also, especially with wordpress. Any good tutorials?

Comment: If you want that specific layout, you don't *need* masonry, in fact you'll probably be frusrated with trying to use it.  I can help, but please - review every comment above - I asked many questions, and only got *some* answers.  If you answer all the questions, I can probably get you an answer to your question, and a way to make this work.

Comment: Well, I couldn't understand some of the questions you asked. Each box is a post that once clicked should appear as lightbox gallery with title and description. I will fix that later with a plugin or code once I get that grid layout I wanted. I don't understand this question (Why is one vertical and one horizontal?). Is there any other questions I've missed?

Comment: Hey I created a codepen code in order to experiment with the code and to see if I can make it work. I couldn't make it work either by pure css3 or flexbox. Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/adXXjZ